# Beanstalkd Source Error

Tags: cakephp, connection, beanstalkd

I am trying to queue a task using beanstalkd plugin in cakephp. However,
I am getting this error:

```
 BeanstalkdSource - Could not connect. Error given was '111: Connection refused'. in [/var/www/*/app/plugins/queue/models/datasources/beanstalkd_source.php, line 72]
```

Can you tell me how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed Beanstalkd and set it running? If you can connect to it OK (run `telnet 127.0.0.1 11300` from the command line, and type `stats` to confirm), then post the connection details, there may be an issue with the PHP side of the connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Configuration of beanstalk was the problem, when i reconfigured it, it got solved.